# Add specific directories to git

Tags: git

I have a script in the folder public_html, of which I would like to track and modify certain directories (recursively) only. Content example:

- public_html/file1.php public_html/file2.php
- public_html/template/custom/file3.php
- public_html/template/custom/dir1/file4.php
- public_html/template/custom/dir2/file5.php
- public_html/module/custom/file6.php
- public_html/module/custom/dir3/file7.php
- public_html/module/custom/dir4/file8.php

Basically, I want to ignore all directories and files except the following directories and their full content:

- public_html/templates/custom/dir1/
- public_html/module/custom/dir1/

What I did is the following:

```
git add public_html/template/custom/dir1
git add public_html/module/custom/dir3
```

But when I push:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git.gitdomain.com:abc/reponame.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Any idea's?

Answer (score 2):

Just found out what I was doing wrong, this did the trick:

```
git remote add origin git@gitsomedomain.com:group/reponame.git
git add public_html/templates/custom/dir1/*
git add public_html/module/custom/dir1/*
git commit -m "first commit"
git push origin master
```